# Docker: PhpStorm Vue syntax highlighting goes away after a few seconds

Tags: docker, vue.js, phpstorm, webstorm, vite

I am having an issue with PhpStorm Vue syntax highlighting going away after a few seconds.

I have already installed the Vue plugin for my IDE and have tried restarting PhpStorm, checking my Vue plugin settings, restarting the TypeScript service, invalidating the caches, and disabling any other plugins that I am not using.

I am using the latest version of PhpStorm and the Vue plugin. I have also tried creating a new Vue project to see if the problem persists, in a blank project I don't have this issue.

My setup is a docker container with node I use as dev environment, whereas I mount my `/home/app` to my local `/app` folder on my host machine.

In this project, I made a vue3 application with Vite.

I recorded this behavior here: [Screenrecord](https://streamable.com/bz68e9)

I am still having trouble and would be grateful for any help.

```
/Users/xxx/Projects/bun-app/app/vue
    ├── README.md
    ├── bun.lockb
    ├── dist
    ├── index.html
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package.json
    ├── postcss.config.cjs
    ├── public
    ├── src
    ├── tailwind.config.ts
    ├── tsconfig.json
    ├── tsconfig.node.json
    └── vite.config.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an open [Bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-59645) on jetbrains YouTrack. You can follow the discussion there and maybe try some of their suggestions.